# Check each cudaMalloc has a cudaFree with bash script

Tags: bash, awk, text-processing

In my code, I have some cudaMallocs that always look like this :

```
cudaMalloc((void**) &solDevicePtr, (NG*G) * sizeof(solDevicePtr[0]));
```

The cudaFree simply look like :

```
cudaFree(solDevicePtr);
```

What I want to do is use a bash script to extract the information "solDevicePtr" from the malloc and then check that in my file the expression cudaFree(solDevicePtr) exists, but for all cudaMalloc(myvar).

How could I do it with bash scripting, awk, ... ? One idea would be to extract and store each cudaMalloc variable and check for a corresponding cudaFree(myvar). One other idea would be to store all cudaMalloc variables in an array and then store all cudaFree variables in another array and compare the arrays after sorting them.

If not success, it would be nice to show what variables are not being freed.

Best regards

Comment: Provide more sample input together with desired output. Also, if it is about cleaning text, do not suppose people know the insights of it, just give an algorithm and what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
code=/path/to/code
for i in $(grep -PRo '(?<=cudaMalloc\(\(void\*\*\) &)([^,]+)(?=, )' "$code"); do
    if ! grep -PRq "cudaFree\\($i\\)"; then
        echo "$i is not freed"
    fi
done
```

**Beware:** if you re-assign the allocated variable it might be freed with that name. Also this whole grepping ignore scopes and program flow so it might be that you allocate with the same name in 2 different places and only free it it one.

Comment: thanks for the response, it's really helpful. Right now, I'm translating a Matlab code where variables are used once and freed once, and I add clear names for variables working on GPU RAM (*devicePtr) and CPU RAM (*hostPtr). So for now it should work nice, but you are right it could give wrong answers for more general and complicated codes.